# Vue Router - Validate Paramater Is In Array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a route:

`/browse/:type/:id?`

How can I validate that `:type` is in an array of allowed values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `beforeEnter` hook.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/browse/:type/:id',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        // ...
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

You can then check the `to` :

> to: Route: the target Route Object being navigated to.

Here is the doc : https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards).

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [{
        path: '/browse/:type/:id?',
        component: Browse,
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            let array = [1, 2, 4]
            if (array.indexOf(to.params.type) == -1)
                alert('Error');
            else
                next()
        }
    }]
})
```

There are other ways to achieve that, you can even use global navigation guard hooks, VueJS docs provided very good examples there, I provide you the link at the above of this answer.